# Children's historical mystery with carved rose pressed to unveil secret

Tags: identification-request, mystery-novels

This has bugged me on and off for years. When I was younger (late 80s - early 90s) I'm sure I read a book from the local library in the UK.  I don't remember many details. I think that it was set around the War of the Roses, and was from the perspective of a child protagonist. I remember there being a carved Tudor rose in a bed room, and I think that when pushed it unveiled some kind of secret.

That's all I remember - and I have never known whether I imagined it, or whether it was a real book. What book was this?

Comment: The books of Geoffrey Trease, Henry Treece and Rosemary Sutcliffe were popular in UK libraries (a few years before then, at least)